# How to update particular value of child in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to update the last message, try multiple methods but little bit confused what is the exact code to update the last message. Thanks in advance. Below is the code that I have tried:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user").child(apiKey)
        databaseReference.orderByChild("api_key").equalTo(loginModel.api_key).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
                    map["last_message"] = message
                    map["last_message_key"] = apiKey
                    //databaseReference.child("api_key").child(loginModel.api_key).updateChildren(map.toMap())
                    //databaseReference.updateChildren(map.toMap())
                    databaseReference.child(snapshot.key!!).setValue(chatUser)
                    Utils.showToast(requireContext(), "Exists")
                }else{
                    Utils.showToast(requireContext(), "Not Exists")
                    userReference.setValue(chatUser)
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Have you read [this part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) of the documentation? If so, what specifically do you not understand?

Comment: Can you post the multiple methods that you have tried? The docs have very specific examples on overwriting data at specific locations.

Comment: If you tried something already and couldn't get it to work, please edit your question to show the [minimal code that any of us can run that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @srinij please check the code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful if you posted the code and also explained the outcome of your code for us to understand better.
Example from the docs: `mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("username").setValue(name);` You can call `.child` all the way to your preferred child and do a `setValue()`.
From your code, the issue might be with the `snapshot.key!!` value which seems to be pointing back to your `apiKey` value.
What you need is `mDatabase.child("user").child("2c3e...").child("-MXH..").updateChildren()`. `setValue()` will overwrite everything in that node. You should debug to see what values you are seeing in each step.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to update properties in Firebase Realtime Database when using a Query, then you should call [getRef()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getRef()) directly on the DataSnapshot object, as explained in the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val apiKeyRef = rootRef.child("user").child("apiKey")
val query = apiKeyRef.orderByChild("api_key").equalTo(loginModel.api_key)
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
                map["last_message"] = message
                map["last_message_key"] = apiKey
                ds.getRef().updateChildren(map)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

I also encourage you to attach a complete listener to all update operations, to always know if something goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of use `set()` method i think you should use `update()` method. In that method you pass the object and firebase detect the properties that has been updated. I'm using it for my project and works fine.